# how to project the nested array as individual object with total count in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this, I need to unwind the array and return the total count. I also need to skip and limit in the result set. Any help in very much appreciated Input

```
[
  {
    "a": "b",
    xyz: [
      {
        "c": "d"
      },
      {
        "e": "f"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "g": "h",
    xyz: [
      {
        "i": "j"
      },
      {
        "k": "l"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected output

```
[
  {
    "xyz": {
      "c": "d"
    }
  },
  {
    "xyz": {
      "e": "f"
    }
  },
  {
    "xyz": {
      "i": "j"
    }
  },
  {
    "xyz": {
      "k": "l"
    }
  },
  "totalCount": 4
]
```

Also I need a paging feature on the above the result data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields
- `$unwind` deconstruct `xyz` array
- `$facet` to separate result and count
- `$skip` to skip number of documents
- `$limit` to limit number of documents
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from `totalCount` array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { xyz: 1 } },
  {
    $unwind: "$xyz"
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      result: [
        { $skip: 0 },
        { $limit: 10 }
      ],
      totalCount: [
        { $count: "totalCount" }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalCount: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$totalCount.totalCount", 0]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_UCtvFlb2wW)